# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.print.CUPSPrinter

Tags: java, linux, printing, cups

I get the following error when sending a job to a printer in Linux.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.print.CUPSPrinter
```

Don't know why the class cannot be found, as it's included in `rt.jar` and i've looked into my `rt.jar` and the class is there.
For more information, my `java -version` shows

> java version "1.6.0_24"
>  Java(TM)
>   SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_24-b07)
>  Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

Thank you in advance

Comment: How you seen that bug report? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=297910 Seems to be the same issue, workaround is to set different (local) DISPLAY value.

Comment: I think, you are trying to run a Java application on a Linux server with no X Server running. Try running with `java -Djava.awt.headless=true ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325579/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-xxx), the class is present, but is not initializing correctly.

In a comment, CodePainters points to this report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=297910 which
implies that $DISPLAY was not set or set correctly.