# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO jboss EAP 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, noclassdeffounderror, jboss-eap-6

We are using the JBoss EAP 6; Everything works well till production environment. But Post deployment in production, we are getting the below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
```

The error happening in one of the servlet where we are creating the Captcha. This is the line where this error is happening :

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
```

Here is the stack trace for the Error :

```
Server:server-three] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[Server:server-three]   at org.fwcms.tc.servlet.Captcha.doGet(Captcha.java:150) [classes:]
[Server:server-three]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:server-three]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:server-three]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:server-three]   ... 36 more
```

This is not happening any other environments. We are deploying the app as ear. Any suggestion/pointers in resolving this will help me a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Regards, 
Manjunath

Comment: have you made sure that ClassPath Env variables are in sync in production or check if there is anything that is overriding Classpath environment variable.

Comment: Do you have a full stackstrace so that we can see where the call is happening?

Comment: Added the required stacktrace Philippe. Let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Hello Vivek, how can I check whether anything is overriding the classpath env?

Comment: Since this is a `NoClassDefFoundError` and not a `ClassNotFoundError` something bad is happening when `ImageIO` is being instantiated.  See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325579/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-xxx

Comment: I had the same problem (but not with JBoss) and I had jai_imageio.jar in classpath. Removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution.
You have to inicializate ImageIO before other operations. 
You can do this by adding:

```
static {
        ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
}
```

eg into your Main class.

Comment: thanks, especially the hint: "initialize before other operations" was extremely important for me (using PDFBOX in Java with PDImageXObject)